# how to remove language dependency in VS 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Does this error caused by language dependencies in VS 2010? I can't compile and keeps generating this error.

> Invalid option '3' for /langversion; must be ISO-1, ISO-2 or Default

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the issue. I choose default and now it's all good:

1. Open the project's Properties page.
2. Click the Build property page.
3. Click the Advanced button.
4. Modify the Language Version property.

Comment: If this doesn't work, you can change the compilerOptions parameter in web.config.